# Erro 500 apos uso do @OnDelete

Tags: java, crud

Estou com dificuldades no uso de @OnDelete

Tenho um blog, que possui usuarios, posts e comentarios nos posts.

fiz o uso do onDelete para apagar os posts em cascata, quando eu excluir um usuario. Inicio da classe usuario:

```java
@Entity
public class Usuario {
    
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy="usuario", orphanRemoval = true)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private List <Post> post = new ArrayList<>();
```

O post e que e o usuario sao apagados normalmente, porem os comentarios daquele usuario em outros posts( que no caso o post foi feito por outro usuario) bugam, e tenho o erro 500 ao dar um get posts.

A ligaçao entre usuario e comentario é onetotone, do lado do comentario.

```java
@Entity
public class Comentario{
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    
    private String conteudo;
    
    @ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name = "post_id")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Post post;
    
    private String nomeUsuario;
    
    @OneToOne(orphanRemoval = true)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Usuario usuario;
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Não ficou muito claro qual é o seu problema, seria melhor você postar o seu stacktrace do erro, mas é provável que o erro que o erro seja relacionado a isto: os mapeamentos de relacionamentos @OneToMany, @OneToOne, etc, devem ser recíprocos, ou seja, se o seu usuário é @OneToMany com os comentários, os comentários devem ser @ManyToOne para seus usuários, pois podem existir muitos comentários para um usuário:

```
@Entity
public class Usuario {
    
   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy="usuario", orphanRemoval = true)
   @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
   private List <Post> post = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Entity
public class Comentario{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    private String conteudo;

    @ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name = "post_id")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Post post;

    private String nomeUsuario;

    @ManyToOne(orphanRemoval = true) // Mudança aqui
    @JsonIgnore
    private Usuario usuario;
}
```

Você pode ler um pouco mais sobre essas associações na documentação do Hibernate [Link](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.6/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many)